# How to show a loader/GIF/text on DOM till data from JSON API is not fetched in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to show a loader or a GIF or a text on my screen before the data is loaded from my JSON API. Please see my code below, in the most simpler manner `listproducts.ts` is fetching the data using `listproduct.service.ts`

Below is my code for `listproduct.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, HttpModule ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ListproductService{
    private _url:string = "http://funiks.com/qbook/api/productmasterjson.php";
    constructor(private _http : Http){}

    listProduct(){
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this._http.post(this._url,{headers:headers})
               .map((response:Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

And `listproduct.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ListproductService } from './listproduct.service';
import { DeleteProductService } from './deleteProduct.service';
import { ProductservicemasterPage } from '../productservicemaster/productservicemaster';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-listproduct',
  templateUrl: 'listproduct.html',
  providers : [ ListproductService,DeleteProductService ],
})
export class ListproductPage implements OnInit{
  public list = [];
  constructor(private _listProduct : ListproductService,private _deleteProduct : DeleteProductService,
              public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this._listProduct.listProduct().subscribe(data => {
       this.list = data;
      console.log(data[0].NAME);
      });
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ListproductService } from './listproduct.service';
import { DeleteProductService } from './deleteProduct.service';
import { ProductservicemasterPage } from '../productservicemaster/productservicemaster';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-listproduct',
  templateUrl: 'listproduct.html',
  providers : [ ListproductService,DeleteProductService ],
})
export class ListproductPage implements OnInit{
  public list = [];
  loading:any;
  constructor(private _listProduct : ListproductService,private _deleteProduct : DeleteProductService,
              public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
   this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });
    }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.loading.present();
     this._listProduct.listProduct().subscribe(data => {
       this.list = data;
      console.log(data[0].NAME);
      this.loading.dismiss();
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please guide how can i use a custom gif

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you could have a loading spinner where the data will show, wrap your code in a try/catch/finally block and replace the data with the spinner till the data is fetched.

Also have a boolean value for the spinner and replace the spinner with the data.

```
showSpinner: boolean = true;
```

HTML

```
<div class="data-wrapper">
   <div *ngIf="list">
      <div *ngFor="let item of list">
         {{ item.NAME }}
      </dvi>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="showSpinner">
      <app-spinner></app-spinner> <!-- your spinner goes here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
try {
  this.http.get<T>(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data=> {
    this.list = data;
  });

}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
finally {
  this.showSpinner = false; //You now have the response, so hide the spinner.
}
```